# Hide LAT / LON coordinates that do not intersect with mapData on Highchart's bubblemap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, geolocation, highmaps

I have a unfiltered set of geo coordinates from all over the world that i show in the world map.

[image]

My map has a drilldown function and by clicking on a country i want to show points only, that belong to the specific country and intersect with mapData. But by rendering the map with the same unfiltered dataset all points are shown, regardless of if they are on the mapData or not.

[image]

So i am wondering if there is a way to only show points on the map that intersect with mapData, something like a 'joinBy' that checks if the lat/lon intersect with the shapes of mapData. Here is a link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/0bu5sjsh/

```
var data = [];


    var wantedPoint = {
        city: "Cologne",
        lat: 50.93333,
        lon: 6.95,
        z: 1017000
    };

    var unwantedPoint = {
        city: "Zürich",
        lat: 47.36667,
        lon: 8.55,
        z: 366765
    };

    data.push(wantedPoint);
    data.push(unwantedPoint);

    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        series: [{
            name: 'Basemap',
            mapData: map,
            borderColor: '#606060',
            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2)',
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.city}'
            },
            name: 'Cities',
            data: data,
            maxSize: '12%',
            color: H.getOptions().colors[0]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: IN your demo I see only single link, could you replicate this scenario which is incorrect?

Comment: What do you mean? The scenario is reduced to the case that i want to solve. The map shows "Cologne" and "Zürich" but i only want "Cologne" to be drawn on the map.

Comment: I prepared simple demo, but please test with expanded data. http://jsfiddle.net/0bu5sjsh/2/

Comment: Hey thanks man, i really appreciate it and tested it with extended data but somehow it only seems to work with points, that are below the map: http://jsfiddle.net/0bu5sjsh/3/ . I did some research and was looking for a further attribute that could tell me if the point is on the map or not, but did not find one. Maybe you have some further ideas? Thanks in advance!